# Loop all value of <LI> in Jquery and change style?

Tags: jquery, css, indexof

How to pass all element in LI using juqey check value and add style?

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="first"><span>1</span></li>
  <li><a href="/blog?page=2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog?page=3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog?page=4">4</a></li>
  <li><span>...</span></li>
  <li><a href="/blog?page=2">></a></li>
  <li class="last"><a href="/blog?page=8">>></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add style background-color:white `<li>` but i want to check if value is ... and add that span style. all that with jquery?

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail.

Comment: I want to check if there is <span>...</span> in <li> and add that span color

Comment: What is a span color?

Comment: Can you post what you want the resulting HTML to look like?  That would help explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("ul.pager").find("span:contains('..')").css("background-color", "white");
```

And yes, `:contains` is case sensitive should you be searching for text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
$('.pager li').each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    if ($li.children().text() === '...') {
        $li.css('background-color', 'white');
    }
});
```